# Grabbing a php base64 image from angularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, base64

I'm trying to grab a 64base encoded string in php from angularJS and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. I've encoded an image that was written to server by the makegray.exe that php runs. Now I'm trying to grab that image and give it back to the angularJS that then displays it for the user. This seems like such a simple problem but I'm stumped as to how to do this.

```
$scope.MakeGray_Button = function(){
    if ($scope.imageUrl) {
        var MakeGray_Form = new FormData();
        MakeGray_Form.append("FileName", $scope.imageUrl);
        $http({
        method : "POST",
        url    : "../opencv/MakeGray/MakeGray.php",
        data   : MakeGray_Form,
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        }).
        success(function(){                     
           // some magic code here that grabs the $base64 variable from php
        })
        .error(function(){});
    }
    else{
        alert("Please upload an image");
    }
}
```

php

```
<?php

$imgname = $_POST["FileName"];
$inputDir = "../../uploads/" . $imgname;
$outputDir = "../../processed/" . $imgname;

$MakeGray = "./makegray " . $inputDir . " " . $outputDir;
$runExec  = exec($MakeGray, $out);

$type = pathinfo($outputDir, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$data = file_get_contents($outputDir);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);

echo "$base64";

?>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?  check the console in Chrome to see what response you're getting from the request.

Comment: Oh I should've mentioned that there's no error I'm getting, it's that I straight up have no clue how to grab the $base64 string that's in php. I've tried a few solutions on stackoverflow that I've found, but none of them work sadly.

Here's what firebug says for me.

http://imgur.com/J02ivaO

Comment: ``success(function(response) { console.log(response)  })`` try this and let us know what response you are getting??

Comment: Ok I will try this and report back

Comment: It said it was (an empty string) in the firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.MakeGray_Button = function(){
    if ($scope.imageUrl) {
        var MakeGray_Form = new FormData();
        MakeGray_Form.append("FileName", $scope.imageUrl);
        $http({
        method : "POST",
        url    : "../opencv/MakeGray/MakeGray.php",
        data   : MakeGray_Form,
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        }).then(function(response){                     
           //response object should hold your base64 image data.
           //you can change src of an img tag with ng-src and let the browser render your image.
        },function(response){});
    }
    else{
        alert("Please upload an image");
    }
}
```

First of all use `.then()` in place of your deprecated functions `.success()` and `.error()`

then also capture `response` as in above code.

you can render the base64 image easily by having it as `src` of an `img` tag. `ng-src` should help for that.

if you want the image as string, you should check `response` object instead.

Comment: This shows response as empty when I try alert(response)

Comment: Ok never mind I found that it does respond the base64, however it isn't displaying. For some reason there are an extra pair of quotes around the base64 string...

http://imgur.com/1NRXpdp

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it to work...

```
$scope.MakeGray_Button = function(){
    if ($scope.imageUrl) {
        var MakeGray_Form = new FormData();
        MakeGray_Form.append("FileName", $scope.imageUrl);
        $http({
        method : "POST",
        url    : "../opencv/MakeGray/MakeGray.php",
        data   : MakeGray_Form,
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        }).
        success(function(data){                     
           $scope.data = data;
           base64 = data;
           $("#img2").prop("src", base64);
        })
        .error(function(){});
    }
    else{
        alert("Please upload an image");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps anyone else trying to display an image to JS from php using base64 encoded strings!